# Cannot queue tasks using Django 1.5, django-celery 3.0.11 and mongodb

Tags: django, django-celery, celery-task, djcelery

everyone. I have problem using  `Django==1.5` with `django-celery==3.0.11`
I get `error: [Errno 61] Connection refused` when I run following code from django shell

```
from data_warehouse.tasks import add
add.delay(4,4)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ('djcelery')
# Settings for Celery Task Scheduler
BROKER_URL = 'mongodb://'
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

data_warehouse.tasks (copied from tutorial)

```
from celery.task import task
@task()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

when I run python manage.py celery worker -l info I get

```
 -------------- celery@Atthaphongs-MacBook-Air.local v3.0.16 (Chiastic Slide)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- [Configuration]
-- * - **** --- . broker:      mongodb://localhost//
- ** ---------- . app:         default:0x10f215810 (djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader)
- ** ---------- . concurrency: 4 (processes)
- ** ---------- . events:      OFF (enable -E to monitor this worker)
- ** ---------- 
- *** --- * --- [Queues]
-- ******* ---- . celery:      exchange:celery(direct) binding:celery
--- ***** ----- 
[Tasks]
  . data_warehouse.tasks.add
/Users/atthaphong/VirtualEnvs/report/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/loaders.py:132: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn("Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never "
[2013-03-23 01:38:22,999: WARNING/MainProcess] /Users/atthaphong/VirtualEnvs/report/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/loaders.py:132: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn("Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never "
[2013-03-23 01:38:23,000: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@Atthaphongs-MacBook-Air.local ready.
[2013-03-23 01:38:23,002: INFO/MainProcess] consumer: Connected to mongodb://localhost//.
/Users/atthaphong/VirtualEnvs/report/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py:274: UserWarning: database name in URI is being ignored. If you wish to authenticate to admin, you must provide a username and password.
  "and password." % (db,))
[2013-03-23 01:38:23,005: WARNING/MainProcess] /Users/atthaphong/VirtualEnvs/report/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py:274: UserWarning: database name in URI is being ignored. If you wish to authenticate to admin, you must provide a username and password.
  "and password." % (db,))
```

when I tried run a task using python shell with this code

```
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery('tasks', broker='mongodb://')
celery.conf.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "mongodb"
@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I get this expected error.

```
[2013-03-23 02:04:30,218: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type     'tasks.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.
Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
```

the problem might come from Celery instance doesn't call the right broker url but I haven't figured it out yet. Do you have any idea about this?

Solved!!
Just add

```
BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'mongodb'
```

To settings.py

Comment: Try setting up rabbitmq and it's worked! so the problem must be from configuration